# How can I create a soft curve in CSS?

Tags: css, background, css-shapes

Is it possible to create a curved block like in the example image using only CSS (no images/svg) ?

[image]

Comment: What's your opposition to svg? It can probably meet your needs, especially inline svg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.curveArea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainBox {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curveSection {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e44627;
  top: 25%;
  left: -50%;
  right: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 10px solid #fdedea;
}
```

```html
<div class="curveArea">
  <div class="mainBox">
    <div class="curveSection"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use this one, I hope it will be helpful

Comment: You could probably even use a psuedo element so you don't have empty markup just for a design element.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this shape as pseudoelement to remove need for additional HTML blocks

```css
.curved-demo {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* just styles for demo */
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.curved-demo:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #e44627;
  border-top: 15px solid #fdedea;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* just styles for demo */
.curved-demo > button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 0;
  text-transform: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="curved-demo">
  Ready to get started
  <button>Schedule a demo</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `radial-gradient` to do this. What's happening is we have one radial gradient that makes an ellipse that is much, much, much larger than the actual element. There is then another ellipse which goes behind that, for the second colour. Something like this:

```css
.thing {
    padding: 100px 20px 50px 20px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 200% at 50% 200%, #f43 90%, #0000 90%),
        radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 200% at 50% 190%, #f87 90%, #0000 90%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}
a {
    color: inherit;
    background: #111;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
    <p>Ready to get started?</p>
    <a href="">Schedule a demo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.background{
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: #e44627;
}

.effect_curve{
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: -50%;
  width: 200% !important;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}
.effect_curve::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  background-color: #e44627;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.effect_curve::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  background-color: #e44627;
  transform: rotate(-0.5deg);
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background effect_curve">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll use `border-radius` but you'll need to get a little creative by doing something like this: `border-radius: 50%/2rem 2rem 0 0;` on a seperate element than the one with your content.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.my-cool-el {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.my-cool-el:before {
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%/2rem 2rem 0 0;
  content:'';
  display: block;
  height: 2rem;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-cool-el">
    Ready To Get Started
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Tried this myself, but as you can see, the extremes (left/right) don't look as curved as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
div{
  border-radius:15px 100px 100px 5px;
  background:#73AD21;
  padding:20px; 
  width:200px;
  height:150px; 
}
```